# Will Migrating from Joomla (1.5) to CakePHP be very difficult? Are there any helpful migration tools out there?

Tags: joomla-1.5, migration, external-script

There's an old site that is running Joomla 1.5 which needs to be brought into the new age and since we mostly just need a Framework and not an entire CMS, CakePHP seemed like a good target to migrate to (although this is open to further discussion/help of course).

Does anyone have any experience with porting Joomla sites of any kind to CakePHP systems? The main pieces that need to be migrated are really just the users and one custom component with its custom routing for SEF URLs.

Ideally we'd like to set things up so that any future implementation of different language versions of the site are as easily scaled to.

Is it generally difficult to port a J1.5 Site to another framework?

Has anyone come across any scripts for porting or at least easing the process of porting Joomla websites to other CMSs or Frameworks?

Thoughts? Tips? Anything?

Comment: You would actually be better off migrating to the Joomla framework. Cake PHP is completely different so your looking at months of work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted by Lodder, It is really hard to migrate Joomla 1.5 site to other framework. You would surely need enough months to accomplish this task.

I rather suggest you to go from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.x. The migration from Joomla! 1.5 to 3.x is a major migration. There are many changes in features and database tables between these two version. It is NOT a one-click update. You will be building/installing a fresh Joomla! 3 installation and then migrating (moving) your data into it. If you haven't already, you may want to start with the Self Assessment and Planning documents.

Following are few steps:

**Prepare a Location for Joomla 3**

Make sure your server environment meets the [technical specifications](http://www.joomla.org/about-joomla/technical-requirements.html) for Joomla! 3 before proceeding.

Create a new database and new user for your Joomla! 3.x site. Document the database name, database username and database password as you’ll need it when you install Joomla 3

**Use Third Party Extension ([Migration Tool](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration))**

I used [SP Upgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/sp-upgrade) It's great tool and transfers all database flawlessly. They have good documentation too. However, it's your choice.

**Migration**

1. Migrate all core data you want to move to Joomla 3.x. If your
   migration tool asks to move Sections and Categories, definitely do
   both. The conversion will happen to categories and nested categories
   automatically.
2. Run the Database Fix by going to Extension **Manager →
   Database** and click the Fix button in the top toolbar.
3. Install your
   new template or converted template so that you can see your content.
   See more about Template Considerations.
4. Add new menus if the tool
   you chose to use didn’t bring over menus. If you want to use split
   menus, set that up now.
5. Add modules if the tool you chose to use didn’t bring over modules. If the tool you chose to use did bring over modules, change the module positions to the positions in your new template if required so that your modules show up and you can see what you’re working with.
6. Check for duplicate alias issues and fix them
7. Check your internal links. If any are broken, fix them
8. Take a backup
9. Install other third-party extensions and configure them (like editors, Akeeba backup, slideshows, or plugins).
10. Take a backup
11. If you have large extensions with data to migrate, do each one according to the developer documentation and then take a backup after each one
12. If your migration tool didn’t move the images, you will want to move your images from the 1.5 site to the 3.x site. Note: keep the /stories directory unless you want to relink all your images. You can start a new organisational structure in the /images directory from here forward if stories is a mess
13. If you are going to add anything to your site or use new core features like Tags, get them set up and configured at this time
14. Check your URLs on the Joomla 3 site and compare to the Joomla 1.5 site. If they are different, document each (an excel spreadsheet is helpful) 1.5 URL and what Joomla 3.x URL they will be going to so that you can do redirects and keep your ranking
15. Take a backup. Clean up more. Test everything. Take a backup.
16. Move or change or add updated data from the 1.5 site to the Joomla 3 site
17. Host it on your hosting space. Make sure you have taken backup at all intervals so that if something goes wrong, you have previous version ready.

> Joomla 3.x is way better than Joomla 1.5 in every aspect. I encourage
>   you to play with it on demo site. End user will never regret to have
>   this awesome CMS.